# Splitting Words Based on Array of String in Java

Tags: java, string, split

I have a static array consist of some arrays of strings

```
    String str = "";
    String[] sA = { "ai", "au", "oi" };
    String[] sB = { "b", "c", "d" };
    String[] sC = { "th", "ng", "sy" };
```

How to split a sentence based on these arrays of strings to add different punctuation from each array of string after splitting to string str?
e.g. :

```
    String s = "This ball color is beautiful";
```

Result if sA's split punctuation is '-', sB's split punctuation is '_', sC's split punctuation is '=':

```
    str = "=is _all _olor is _e-tiful";
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't see any split here but surrounding elements from array with `-` .

Comment: I don't have any idea besides using
String[] splitS = line.split("ai||au||oi");

Comment: And what is wrong with `line.split("ai|ao|oi")`? (except fact that there is no `ao` in your array)

Comment: I need to split with many condition of strings to add punctuation after the splitting is done

Comment: OK, but you still didn't describe problem you are facing while writing your code. You need to ask specific question (and requirement != question).

Comment: OK. thanks for your corrections.

Answer (score 0):

You dont split, finally.

Rather, use replace (one pattern,"_")  with all your arrays of pattern.

Beware: no ambiguity !

like that:

```
for (int i=0;i<sA.length; i++)
    s=s.replace(sA[i],"-");
```

etc.